# Android Project Failed (React Native) - Execution failed for task ':app:packageDebug' Duplicate files copied in APK META-INF/LICENSE

Tags: java, android, react-native

Just upgraded from React Native .26 to .29 and am getting the below error when trying to run my Android project. I've gone to those files and changed the names, moved the folders, etc. They're rebuild, and duplicated, on each build. Any idea where this could be happening from?

> ... ... 
>   :app:preDexDebug UP-TO-DATE :app:dexDebug UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:validateDebugSigning :app:packageDebug Error: duplicate files
>   during packaging of APK
>   /Users/nhyland/Documents/react-native/BidSmart/android/app/build/outputs/apk/app-debug-unaligned.apk  Path in archive: META-INF/LICENSE   Origin 1:
>   /Users/nhyland/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core/2.4.1/b130bcfb5a9c410c3cbd2e0adec9437e69a39e2c/jackson-core-2.4.1.jar
>     Origin 2:
>   /Users/nhyland/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-annotations/2.4.1/55605135bd7b836612e0bba7037c9669f6ccf89f/jackson-annotations-2.4.1.jar
>   You can ignore those files in your build.gradle:  android {
>   packagingOptions {
>         exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'    }     } :app:packageDebug FAILED
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:packageDebug'.
>
>   > Duplicate files copied in APK META-INF/LICENSE      File 1: /Users/nhyland/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core/2.4.1/b130bcfb5a9c410c3cbd2e0adec9437e69a39e2c/jackson-core-2.4.1.jar
>   >     File 2:
>   >     /Users/nhyland/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-annotations/2.4.1/55605135bd7b836612e0bba7037c9669f6ccf89f/jackson-annotations-2.4.1.jar
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
>
> BUILD FAILED
>
> Total time: 5.727 secs Could not install the app on the device, read
>   the error above for details. Make sure you have an Android emulator
>   running or a device connected and have set up your Android development
>   environment:
>   https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/android-setup.html

Answer (score 1):

Fixed by adding the below to build.gradle:
Broken for other reasons now :-)

```
packagingOptions {
            exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
            exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
      }
```